# Stock prices using candlesticks

Tags: stocks, technical-analysis

Does the close price of a candlestick necessarily have to coincide with the opening price of the next candlestick?

Answer (score 2):

No it does not.  Candlesticks really have nothing to do with this, a stock price can open different then the previous day's close.

Examining the chart of TSLA provides an example
it closed on 1/18/17 at 238.8
it opened on 1/19/17 at 243.7

In candlestick parlance is is known as a "gap up".